# Not getting Response from Backend Nuxtjs Auth

Tags: node.js, authentication, axios, nuxt.js

I'm pretty new to vuejs and nuxtjs. I'm trying to make a simple app with authentication and for it I'm using NuxtJS Auth Module with Axios.

I have setup a basic NodeJS backend. The problem I'm having is that the backend is not receiving the request. I tested it with Postman and with Postman its working fine.

Here is the revelant code.

Backend: userRoutes.js

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const user = require('../../models/dummyUser');

    module.exports = (app) => {

        app.post('/user/login', (req, res, next) => {
            const { body } = req;
            const { username } = body;
            const { password } = body;

            //checking to make sure the user entered the correct username/password combo
            if (username === user.username && password === user.password) {
                //if user log in success, generate a JWT token for the user with a secret key
                jwt.sign({ user }, 'privatekey', { expiresIn: '1h' }, (err, token) => {
                    if (err) { console.log(err) }
                    res.send(token);
                });
            } else {
                console.log(username)
                console.log('ERROR: Could not log in');
            }
        })
```

Front end: Login.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Login</h1>

    <UserAuthForm buttonText="Login" :submitForm="loginUser" :hasName="false" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import UserAuthForm from "@/components/UserAuthForm";
export default {
  components: {
    UserAuthForm
  },
  methods: {
    loginUser(loginInfo) {
      // debugger
      console.log(loginInfo);
      this.$auth.loginWith("local", {
        data: loginInfo
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

and i nuxt.config.js I have

```
axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000'
  },
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/user/login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'body' },
          logout: { url: '/user/logout', method: 'post' },
          user: { url: '/api/auth/user', method: 'get', propertyName: 'user' }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

When I click on the Login button and check the network connections in Developer tools I get failed in the call to the API. Like I mentioned, with PostMan If I make a POST request to http://localhost:8000/user/login with the keys username and password I get a response with the Token.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From where are you making the axios call?

Comment: From the loginUser function. this.$auth.loginWith("local", {
        data: loginInfo
      });